# Get data from subform to main form

Tags: php, webforms, wordpress

I have a structure like :

```
<form id="first_form">
 <fieldset>something</fieldset>
 <fieldset>
   <iframe><html> ... 
      <form id="second_form">
         <input type="hidden" value="**some_value**" name="hidden_data" />
      </form>
    </html></iframe>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

What i need from this structure is to take the value from "hidden_data" in main form, and then to go post in database. I tried to prin_t($_POST); die; (after submitting first form) but i don't receive any input from second_form. Does somebody have an idea? Regards

Note : It's about wordpress plugin **tdo mini forms** 
Note 2 : I want to get an url from an uploaded file (url which i get after i submit second_form) and then add as post meta, using first_form.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just dump HTML inside of an `iframe` element. Any children of `iframe` are simply there to be displayed if the browser can't handle `iframe`s.

Also, nested `form` elements doesn't validate (in HTML 4.01 Strict anyway, and I doubt in any others).

Comment: See my answer to SoloGhHoST's post

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an iframe with a form in it?  Seems strange.  And having HTML inside of that isn't what it is `<iframe>` tag is used for.  Would be best to just have 1 form `id="first_form"` with the hidden element from the form `id="second_form"` in it.  You can't put a form inside of another form, there can only be one at any given time.

Comment: Plugin makes this structure and it's bit hard to modify. I didn't specify but in second for also i have more inputs, not hidden. Basically second for is for uploading a file (including input type="file" and an submit) and i want to send the file name in main form.